# Transaction Log too big in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions

I have a database with a transaction log that is too big (~ 63GB). How can I manage it? And how can I reduce it's size? Will I lose any data?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: [See, read and learn from Transaction Log Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345583%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) on Technet - it explains the ins and outs of how and why to manage your transaction log

Comment: Yeah. No excuse for never reading any documentation. And this so absolutely is not a programming question - dba.stackexchange.com is the right place, but you will get face slapped there for the demonstrated inability to do the basics of a professional: reading documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments... I read this Article yesterday. and also I reduced my transaction log by two articles which found one of them here. and also I  am sorry for posting my question in wrong place.